# How do I add a new contact to Highrise via email?

Tags: crm

Sometimes I get partnership offers from people but I'm not ready to work with them yet.

I'd like to have an easy way to add them to Highrise (the 37 signals app) and tag them.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can email a contact into Highrise using your 'Highrise Dropbox' email address. You can find this address in `Settings > My Info > Email dropbox`.

You can bcc Highrise when communicating with a prospect, or you can forward an email from the prospect to your Highrise dropbox. If the contact exists, Highrise will attach the email to their case. If the contact doesn't exist, Highrise will create it automatically.

See the Highrise demo here:
http://highrisehq.com/emaildropbox

I don't think you can tag them at the same time, but you can create a Highrise task (to *remind* you to tag them) using the process above.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Gmail, you can check out Ecquire. Instead of using Bcc and Dropbox, Ecquire will automatically capture an email for you and find the right account associated with that email to save it. If it's a new contact, Ecquire will create a new account with all the pertinent information.